# MSMQ Distributed Transaction (DTC) cannot import transaction

Tags: msmq, msmq-transaction

I need to receive, process and send a message in one transaction. Since MSMQ does not support Transactional Remote Receive, I use DTC for that. Right now, I can't even receive a message. Here's the code I use for that:

```
string queueName = "trxwrite";
string serverName = "mqtest";

using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue(string.Format(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:{0}\{1}", serverName, queueName));
    mq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] {typeof (string)});

    Message message = mq.Receive(MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
    ts.Complete();
}
```

- The queue is transactional.
- DTC is enabled on the server `mqtest`
  and configured to allow inbound and outbound.
- The firewall is set to allow all MSMQ and DTC requests.

I get the following error Message: *Cannot import the transaction*.
Can anyone help? 
Also, how does my client machine know that it should use the DTC on the server for the transaction? Can't tell from the samples I have found so far...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously DTC has to be installed and configured to allow network access on both client and server. That way, this snippet works fine:

```
string queueName = "trxwrite";
string queue2Name = "trxread";
string serverName = "mqtest";
Parallel.For(0, 300, (int i) =>
                        {
                            using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
                            {
                                MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue(string.Format(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:{0}\{1}", serverName, queueName));
                                mq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] { typeof(DateTime) });

                                Message message = mq.Receive(MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);
                                DateTime createDt = (DateTime)message.Body;

                                MessageQueue mq2 = new MessageQueue(string.Format(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:{0}\{1}", serverName, queue2Name));
                                mq2.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] { typeof(DateTime) });

                                Message messageToSend = new Message(createDt);
                                mq2.Send(messageToSend, MessageQueueTransactionType.Automatic);

                                ts.Complete();
                            }
                        });
```